# Multi-Threaded Excel processing with Qt?

Tags: multithreading, qt, activex

I'm trying to process an Excel sheet to make some treatment on the data in it with Qt (4.6.3).
I've tried to use an `QAxWidget excel("Excel.Application")` as used [here](http://www.qtforum.org/article/28084/excel-sheet-in-qt.html).

I tried first to use it in a simple method, everything works fine but the GUI freezes for some time, so I tried to implement it in a different `QThread`.

As some say, it's not allowed to use inherited classes from `QWidget` in other threads than the main one.
I also tried this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834781/calling-qaxwidget-method-outside-of-the-gui-thread), but there's a runtime error anyway.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
void MainDialog::extractData()
{
    QAxWidget excel("Excel.Application");
    excel.setProperty("Visible", false);

    QAxObject * workbooks = excel.querySubObject("WorkBooks");
    workbooks->dynamicCall("Open (const QString&)", ui->lineEditAdress->text());
    QAxObject * workbook = excel.querySubObject("ActiveWorkBook");
    QAxObject * worksheet = workbook->querySubObject("Worksheets(int)", 1);

    // ... some work here...

    workbook->dynamicCall("Close (Boolean)", false);
    excel.dynamicCall("Quit (void)");
}
```

What I'm doing wrong ? Is there a better way to get the job done ? Better idea than ActiveX ?

Thanks.

**Edit:**
As Raiv said, I replaced `QAxWidget` by `QAxObject`

Just call in the run() of the thread:

```
// ...
CoInitialize(0);
QAxObject excel("Excel.Application");
// ...
```

and it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try QAxObject instead of QAxWidget, and it would work in another thread. Just don't forget to call CoInitialize() there.

Answer (score -1):

I want to add more:

void Fn:Example(){

```
 CoInitialize(0); // function used to initialize COM libraries in a process
 // code etc
 ...
 CoUninitialize(); // function used to release COM resources and end COM usage in a process
```

}